# What's the right way to get the number of variable variables

Tags: coldfusion

Let's say I have a form with an undetermined number of values with names such as follows:

```
PARAM1VCHRNAME
PARAM2VCHRNAME
PARAM3VCHRNAME
...
```

And I want to loop through these using quoted naming as described in this article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/152-dynamic-coldfusion-variables-via-quoted-naming.htm

But in order to do so I need to find how many of these items exist in order to set up my loop.

I have ran across this situation in the past and the only way I could think to do it was to write some javascript to into a hidden field into the form with how many items there were. But this was a messy solution because it would screw things up if the user clicked the back button. I'm sure there has to be a way to do this on the server side.

Thank you

@kevin

Ok, I wrote a thing to loop though the form field names and filter them. Not the prettiest code I have ever written. But it works. Thanks for your help.

```
<cfset totalParams = 0>
<cfloop index="i" list="#Form.FieldNames#" delimiters=",">
     <cfif LEFT(i,5) eq 'PARAM' AND 
           RIGHT(i,8) eq 'VCHRNAME' AND 
           LSParseNumber(Replace(Replace(i, 'PARAM',''),'VCHRNAME','')) gt totalParams>
           <cfset totalParams = LSParseNumber(Replace(Replace(i, 'PARAM',''),'VCHRNAME',''))>
     </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You could just loop over all the form fields, filtered to only the ones that match a particular string or regular expression.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you ultimately doing with the values? Do you need to associate each field with something else, like related fields with the same number ie Other1Field, Other2Field, etc... Side note, since most scopes are structures, why not just use structure notation?

Comment: You could always give your form fields meaningful names.

Comment: @Leigh, there are several variables for each parameter. Param1Name, Param1Value, etc. What I'm doing with them is looping through them to put them into a database table.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is `PARAM#i#VCHRNAME` and the sequence always starts with 1 and it's continuous, you can try looping continuously until you cannot find the field name anymore from the `FORM` scope:

```
function findLastVchrname()
{
  var i=1;
  while (structKeyExists(FORM, 'PARAM#i#VCHRNAME'))
    i++;

  return i;
}
```

If the series is not continuous, then you need to loop through the `form.fieldnames` and count how many of them passes regex `"^PARAM(\d)+VCHRNAME$"` with [reFind()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REFind)

Or if you want to be fancy, try [listFilter()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListFilter) on `form.fieldNames`, use a filter function with determine if it matches the pattern, then do a [listLen()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListLen) on the result.

If you use CF11 and also want to be Extra fancy, try to refactor the logic above into [ListReduce()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListReduce)